# Ubuntu on laptop

Tags: system-installation, distro-recommendation

A friend of mine asked me for a favour; she uses windows 7 on her laptop with these system specs:

> Video : intel HD graphics family
>   Procesor : intel pentium B950 CPU@2.10 GHz
>   RAM : 4 GB
>   Hard disc : 500 GB

She complains about how her laptop is overheating and running slow. So I was wondering if installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS would solve the problem, at least reduce the overheating and boost the performance?

She asked me if I could install linux on her laptop, as I suggested that linux should run better than windows.

So, would Ubuntu 14.04 be a good choice or should I go with some more lightweight Linux, given the fact that system components are not quite well?

Comment: With this hardware every Ubuntu [Flavor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) should run without performance problems. To check if there is really a overheating problem you should [check the temperatures](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto) and post your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest installing [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) even though you have plenty of ram, lubuntu will use a lot less resources and run cooler.

I recommend you clean out your laptop and use a chilling pad to help cool your laptop down.

Comment: ...and what about Xubuntu? I heard it is a good choice for older machines...And as I said, it is not my laptop, so I would not dare to perform any other actions then installing new OS. And yes, the thing is I have tried Lubuntu once as I was trying to find "the one" for my machine, and yet I could not notice that annoying issue that you can't empty your trash via desktop trash icon. Since I am installing new OS to a person who got used to a "windows-type-OS", I smell that could be a problem for her too. So, thoughts about Xubuntu?

Comment: Xubuntu is easier on resources then ubuntu but not as easy as lubuntu. Just make a livecd or live usb and give it a try. Here is a solution to the trash can icon issue. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220160

Answer (score 1):

My laptop has very (very) similar system requirements. Same hard drive, same RAM, and almost the same processor, and it runs Ubuntu very well. It sounds like that laptop would run Ubuntu 14.04 perfectly, just as mine does.